# NGINX Redirect all to https except one directory

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I've searched stackoverflow looking for an answer and everything that has been suggested, I've tried without success.

My site redirects users to always use SSL (https). However, I have a chat application that does not work on SSL because it is not licensed using the ssl url. I can't get the devs to update the license but that's another story.

So because of this, I have allow non-ssl (http) to just this chat application that resides in a sub-directory called chat.

Here is my config, and it doesn't work:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {  # the default location redirects to https
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location /chat/ {}  # do not redirect requests for chat location
  # ...
}


server {
  listen 443;

  location /chat/ {  # redirect https iframe requests to http server
      return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
  # ...
}
```

I've tried many combinations of things including 302 instead of 301 (clearing my browser cache while trying this), trailing slash vs non-trailing slash. Nothing seems to work.

What's crazy is this used to work, until I updated the SSL block to be more secure and get an A+ tag. Not sure what I removed or added that may have affected this.

And last, if I clear my browser cache, and go directly to

> `http://example.com/chat/test.htm`

, it does not redirect which is correct. However, once I go to https://example.com, then to http://example.com/chat/test.htm, the browser says that there are endless redirects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show your logs? Did you try it in browser's "private window"?

Comment: uzsolt, I was able to discover the issue, see my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I added HSTS headers to my SSL block which tells the browser to force SSL. This was causing endless redirects. I changed the age on the HSTS directive to 0 so hopefully this will reset my users browsers.